# Is $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$??

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$   be analytic. Let $u=Re f(z)$ and $v=Im f(z)$ where $f(z)=u+iv$.

Which are correct?

1. $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$
2. $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$
3. $u_{xy}+u_{yx}=0$
4. $v_{xy}-u_{yx}=0$

Since $u_x=v_y,u_y=-v_x$ .Since $u,v$ have continuous partial derivatives so $u_{xy}=u_{yx},v_{xy}=v_{yx}$.Combining I got 1,2,3 as correct options but in the answer 1,3 are correct.

Where am I wrong?Please help

Comment: Maybe you should post how you got 2... although I would agree with you

Comment: Are you sure the items are written correctly? As it stands 1,2 are true but $f (z)=iz^2$ gives counterexamples for 3,4.